# Deriving Milne's predictor of order four from extrapolation polynomial

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, differential-equations, difference-equations

I am trying to derive the following Milne's predictor formula of order four for the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ from an extrapolation polynomial of degree four. $$y_{n+1} = y_{n-3}+\frac{4h}{3}(2y_n'-y_{n-1}'-2y_{n-2}').$$

We use the following extrapolating polynomial $$y(x)=a+b(x-x_{n-3})+c(x-x_{n-3})(x-x_{n-2})+d(x-x_{n-3})(x-x_{n-2})(x-x_{n-1})+e(x-x_{n-3})(x-x_{n-2})(x-x_{n-1})(x-x_{n}).$$

Since we want the predictor formula in the prescribed form, I used the following information

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{At } x=x_{n-3}, y=y_{n-3}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}(x_{n-2},y_{n-2}) = f(x_{n-2},y_{n-2})\\
\frac{dy}{dx}(x_{n-1},y_{n-1}) = f(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})\\
\frac{dy}{dx}(x_{n},y_{n}) = f(x_{n},y_{n})
\end{eqnarray}

to obtain the following

\begin{eqnarray}
y_{n-3} = a\\
b+hc-h^2d+2h^3e = f(x_{n-2},y_{n-2})\\
b+3hc+2h^2d-2h^3e = f(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})\\
b+5hc+11h^2d+6h^3e = f(x_{n},y_{n})
\end{eqnarray}

However, I do not know how to solve for $b,c,d,e$ from the above three equations to obtain the required formula. Can someone help?

PS: I asked the same question in math.stackexchange where I couldn't get a response yet. Here's the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733162/deriving-milnes-predictor-of-order-four-from-extrapolation-polynomial).

Comment: Isn't this linear in b,c,d,e? If so, use linear algebra.

Comment: @joro Since there are three equations and four unknowns, there may be infinitely many solutions. I don't know how to get that specific solution so that it will lead to the above predictor formula.

Comment: I've added some comments on the math.SE site.  This definitely isn't a research question, so it's not appropriate for MO.

Comment: Can someone please tell me if the predictor formula mentioned above can be derived in this way at all?

Comment: This is said in a book that this predictor formula can be obtained in this way.   As far I see, this is a valid research level question as no one seems to be able to answer yet.